# Swift convert HexString to Integer

Tags: swift, byte, arrays

I have a data source in String example

```
HexString = "72AE"
```

and i would like to convert it into byte and store into byte array

```
bytearray = [72, AE]  //UInt8
```

i know i can do this by

```
let hexaString = "72AE"
let resultArray = hexaString.characters.map{Int(strtoul(( String($0)), nil, 16))}

print(resultArray)  // "[7, 2, 10, 14]"
```

but it is not returning the value i want. I have also tried to chop it into hexaString1 = "72" hexaString2 = "AE" but still i can't manage to get the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you

```
let hexaString = "72AE"
var byteArray = [UInt8]()
byteArray += hexaString.utf8  // Convert into byte array

// Retain the orginal string from byte array
let stringFromByteArray = NSString(bytes: byteArray, length: byteArray.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: I assume he wanted 0x72 and 0xAE returned, That just gets 0x37 (7),  0x32 (2),  0x41 (A),  0x45 (E)